# LuaTeX error "Parsing CFF DICT"

Tags: luatex

The following code is a minimal example of a problem I am having often in some of my documents. When compiling with `lualatex` with the `x86-64-linux` binary (in TeXLive 2013 with the latest updates) results in

```
!LuaTeX error (file /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/
lmroman10-regular.otf): Parsing CFF DICT failed. (error=-1)
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

The error is not present when using the Windows binary.

The example code isn't very productive, but it illustrates the problem. Removing pretty much any line from this example results in proper compilation, but the problem is much harder to get rid of in my real documents which are much longer.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\newcommand{\Item}{%
    \directlua{math.log(0,10)}%
    \begin{tabular}{l}
        1\\1\\1\\1\\1
    \end{tabular}%
    \vspace{\baselineskip}%
    \par%
}

\begin{document}

\Item
\Item
\Item
\Item
\Item
\Item
\Item
\Item
\Item

\end{document}
```

Is this a bug in `LuaTeX` or is there something inherently wrong with the example above? I would like to be able to avoid this error in the future if it is not a bug and I am causing it with something in my code that I should not do.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `math.log(0.10)` (period instead of comma)?

Comment: the comma in `math.log(0,10)` is to make 10 the base for the logarithm, Lua returns `-inf` in this case

Comment: But log(0) doesn't make sense. If the comma is an allowed syntax (I couldn't verify this) then you should use something like `math.log(1,10)`.

Comment: This is the proper syntax in Lua 5.2 which is used by current versions of `LuaTeX`. While in the mathematical sense `log(0)` doesn't make sense but Lua returns `-inf`. This doesn't cause issues in many other contexts but for some reason here is helps contribute to a font-based error and I don't know why.

Comment: I found now the new syntax in the lua 5.2 manual. I think you should ask this on the luatex bug tracker. tracker.luatex.org

Comment: Btw: You should add to the bug report that it is related to the log(0). (I can reproduce the problem with miktex, but not with TL13).

Comment: great i will add that in now

Comment: Perhaps related: http://tracker.luatex.org/view.php?id=820

Comment: I had the same problems when mixing CFF and TrueType fonts on Windows 64 bit.

Comment: This was fixed in LuaTeX 0.78.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug which is fixed in the latest release of the software in question.

Comment: I think this question can safely be deleted (if that is normal policy) since the bug report I filed on the LuaTeX bug tracker comes up quite easily when looking for the issue, and that site includes a description of the cause and the version when it was resolved.